# Does upvotes prevent flagging as very low quality?

Tags: support, flagging, review, low-quality, up-votes

In the first post review queue I see [an answer](https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/148072), which I want to flag as very low quality. But when I click on flag, the very low quality option is missing from the list of options.

The answer currently has a positive score of 1. Would that cause the very low quality flag to be made inaccessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the very low quality flag is available only for posts scored 0 or below.

In any case, you can't flag that answer because I already deleted it.

Comment: It hadn't been deleted yet, when I tried to flag it. Do you agree that flagging as very low quality would have been appropriate for that answer?

Comment: Yes, very low quality would be appropriate. The answer was complete nonsense, and even after poking at it with some moderator-only tools I'm still not sure how it got an upvote.